# What is the difference between mass defect and mass deficit?

Tags: mass, nuclear-physics, terminology, mass-energy, binding-energy

Is there any difference between the mass defect and the mass deficit?

I have read that the mass defect of a nuclide is never negative and have also been told that the mass defect is the same as the mass deficit, which can be negative. Is it purely a sign convention? As a result of this is the binding energy of a nuclide ever negative?